# That does not contain a constructor that takes 3 arguments at base(context,0,items) in BaseAdapter

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

```
public class ListViewAdapter : BaseAdapter<IMenuItemsType>
        {
            private Context context;
            private List<IMenuItemsType> items;
            private LayoutInflater inflater;

            public ListViewAdapter(Context context, List<IMenuItemsType> items) : base(context,0,items)
            {
                this.context = context;
                this.items = items;
                this.inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
            }
```

`base(context,0,items)` That does not contain 
 a constructor that takes 3 arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to use `ArrayAdapter`, not `BaseAdapter`.

That is where you find the `(context, resource, list)` constructor.